# How to reset a BufferedInputStream after changing the underlying FileInputStream's position

Tags: java, serialization, inputstream, java-io

I'm trying to perform random read/write operations on serializable objects in a file.

I know I can set the position of a `FileInputStream` and then wrap the appropriate Input Streams around it like this:

```
InputStream file = new FileInputStream(fileName);
((FileInputStream)file).getChannel().position(pos);
InputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream(file);
ObjectInput input = new ObjectInputStream (buffer);
```

But what if I have to change the position of the `FileInputStream` again later on to perform another write operation?

How do I change/reset the `BufferedInputStream` so it can perform right? Do I even have to?

Also, I am assuming that any answer to this questions also apply to an Output scenario?!

Comment: You will need to use the mark and reset methods. The mark() method allows you to mark a spot to jump back to for some types of input streams.For example you could mark the stream prior to reading an object. Then reset to be able to reread it. Alternatively, use RandomAccessFile for this purpose.

Comment: @Jason Where did he say he only wants to jump *back*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with EJP: you are going down the wrong rabbit hole here in case you would be asking for a "generic" solution that works for arbitrary classes.

But your comments make it clear that you specially designed your class(es) to result in "equally sized records" when using serialization **properly**.

What you need to do:

- forget about using FileInput/OutputStream, instead:
- use [RandomAccessFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) - as that one allows you to read / write bytes at random points in your file
- for each object to deal with, use its **own, dedicated**
  [ByteArrayInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html) (resp. output) object.

In other words: in order to make this work, you can't read/write more than one object in one shot. You want serialization to be a simple mechanism to turn a single object into a stream of bytes; and vice versa.

But keep in mind: you will spend a lot of energy for a very restricted use case. As soon as your classes would need to be more complex, you are *broken* - as you now end up with **different** sized byte representations.

So the real answer here: while your idea can be implemented (and is a nice learning exercise around serialization and file access), you are re-inventing the wheel here! And your version of that wheel is very restricted, hard to enhance; and probably resulting in mediocre performance.

So in case this is intended for a "real" product: better turn to any *real* database, instead of building your own DBMS.

Comment: The goal here is to implement a DBMS. So I'll store objects in a file and keep a sort of pointer to their position. All the objects classes are defined so they have a fixed size. They all have attributes that are either primitives or fixed-size arrays of primitives. But I understand your point. And if my way of defining a class doesn't assure that the object, once serialized, will have a fixed size, then I'll have to change my approach.

Comment: @BrunoNascimento It doesn't assure that, because of handles: see my answer. You will have to change your approach.

Comment: BTW: I updated my answer, and I will replace the loosely written class names with exact content later on.

Comment: I am not sure if that plays a role here. The op says that his class is using primitive values and arrays of those only. When you serialize such objects (one by one!) I would expect the outcome to be equally sized byte records.

Comment: @GhostCat I've already covered that. The *object itself* will be serialized with a `classdesc` *handle*, unless it is the first one in the stream.

Comment: That is my point: you would serialize using a UNIQUE object output stream for each object. The file contains byte records, and you serialize each object completely by its own. The output stream can only optimize on handles when you serialize more than one object into that stream.

Comment: Separating the individual object serialization from the final output stream writes can do what is desired. I have done it before but with kryo serialization.

Comment: Thanks. But hint - you upvoted in the wrong place - you should have clicked on the triangle near to my answer, not on my comment :-)

Comment: I'll try that. Also I imagine I could simply implement functions on each class to convert the objects into byte arrays, thus eliminating handles or any other metadata.

Comment: And just for the record: please don't forget about upvoting / accepting at some point while being lost in the depths of implementing this. I put quite some efforts into this answer and the discussion....

Comment: @EJP I reworded my answer ... let me know if it now meets your quality standards ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I think the easier thing you can do is create a new `BufferedInputStream` any time you hav to move the position on the `FileInputStream`.

Comment: Or any other way.

Comment: You will also need to create a new ObjectInputStream at the new position, of course.  That's necessary anyway, because ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream don't process each object independently -- they maintain and use information about all the objects that have been seeen so far.  Each object that you want to access independently needs to be serialized or deserialized with its own object stream.

Comment: @MattTimmermans *And* serialize the object wih a new `ObjectOutputStream` to that position.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to perform random read/write operations on serializable objects in a file.

Stop right there (and back away). You can't do this via any means. The object stream relies on its own past history, via a system of 'handles', for both classes and objects. You will not in general succeed in this, however you try to realize it in code, for example, by eliminating the buffered stream.

**EDIT** Serialization does not re-serialize an already serialized object. For example, a `StreamClassDesc`, which is provided with every object. Instead it just serializes a 'handle' to it. So even if you just serialize two `Strings`, you can't deserialize the second one on its own, because the classdesc handle refers to a prior object in the stream. See the Object Serialization Specification. There is also the stream header to consider.

Comment: And now that I typed my own answer, feedback is welcome.

Comment: @GhostCat Why? `RandomAccessFile` is irrelevant. *Every* implementation possibility is irrelevant, as I said, for the reason I stated.

Comment: Thinking about it... Yes, agreed.